# Can my syrupy jelly be processed again to make it set, or do I need to start over?

Tags: canning, jelly, pectin

I have a blackberry watermelon jelly that I made and it didn't set up.  I waited about 3 weeks for it to set up and then reprocessed it, adding more pectin.  I added 1 1/2 packages of pectin (it was a large batch) and it still didn't set up.  I've looked on-line but can't find anyone who's actually reprocessed a second time.  People have asked but no one has done it to answer.

Can I reprocess it or do I just have to resign myself to having syrup?

Comment: Did you do something like cut back the amount of sugar in the jelly, vs. the recipe? That can cause it to not set.

Comment: **1)** Jam needs a proper mix of pectin, acid, and sugar. Are you following a recipe? If so, have you altered anything, like fresh vs. frozen fruit, ratios, etc.? **2)** Your jelly should be set up when it cools to room temperature. No time in the fridge will change this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [a chilled plate to test](http://foodinjars.com/2010/07/canning-101-how-to-ensure-that-your-jam-sets/) your batch before canning it next time. Pectin does not firms up with time, just temperature.

I would suspect that the watermelon juice has made your jelly too dilute, and you'll need to boil your jelly down further.

Comment: Cold plate trick is a good idea!